# Stop contenteditable from defocusing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on implementing *Froala text editor* into my website.

All looks good except for the fact that when i click the button_bar `div` or it's children, the `contenteditable` `div` unfocuses. This is a problem because i have a background color applied to the focus state of the `contenteditable` `div`.

How can i stop the `contenteditable` `div` from deselecting, when clicking on the child `buttons` of the sibling div?

A visual representation would look a little like this..

```
<div class='editor'>

    <div class="button_bar">
        <button>
        <button>
        <button>
        etc
    </div>

    <div contenteditable="true" class="content_area">
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: Not sure about what you're after. `focus` the *content area* when clicking on the `button`?

Comment: @HashemQolami To keep the content focused when clicking anywhere in the 'buttonbar' or its child `buttons`.

Comment: Does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/jbP5E/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xus8y/)

```
$('.editor').on('click', function(e){
    if($(e.target).is('button'))
        $(this).find('div[contenteditable]').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the div focused again upon clicking any of the buttons. There is a slight gap where focus is lost and immediately regained though.

```
$('.button_bar button').click(function (e) {
    console.log('clicked');
    $('#content').focus(); // if we give the contendeditable div an id of 'content'
});
```